# JSF - 2 a4j:actionParam in one commandlink bug

Tags: java, jsf

I have such structure in my jsp:

```
<h:commandLink action=#{docbean.save}>
    <a4j:actionParam name="somename" value="bill_all" assignTo="#{billdoc.billType}"/>
    <a4j:actionParam name="somename" value="bill_document" assignTo="#{docbean.doctype}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

While debugging i saw, that billdoc.billtype and docbean.doctype have the same values: "bill_document".

Is it bug? If not, then how can i put value to my managed-bean?

**UPDATED:**

Found the answer:

I had two actionParams with one name. ActionParam is f:actionListener + f:param. So, if you have several actionparams with one name, you will have the problem i had. RichFaces and JSF doesn't warn you about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a space here `<a4j:actionParamvalue` - before `value`

Second, You may try this instead of `<a4j:actionParam>`:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="bill_all" target="#{billdoc.billType}" />
```

You may need to put `immediate="true"` on your `commandLink` if there are validation errors in your form. You can view these errors by adding `<rich:messages />` ontop of the page.

Comment: I tried replace <a4j:actionParam> with <f:setPropertyActionListener>, but nothing happens. Form is submitted, bet action does not execute. Maybe <f:setPropertyActionListener> is not allowed inside <h:commandLink>?

Comment: @Yurish - it is allowed. Check your logs and check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an a4j:commandLink. Or - if you stick to h:commandLink - try embedding your a4j:actionParams in an a4j:support tag.